# Forgotten how to achieve this: distinct counts from data based on a lookup value

Tags: excel, excel-formula, array-formulas

**SEE BELOW FOR THE ANSWER.**

I remember solving this with an array formula a while back, but I haven't got the original workbook any more and the answer is completely escaping me.

Here's sample data:

```
Salesman    Product
Bill        Apple
Bob         Orange
Bill        Banana
Bob         Apple
Bill        Apple
Bob         Orange
Bill        Apple
```

What I'm wanting to do is make another table with the number of DISTINCT items Bob and Bill have sold. i.e:

```
Salesman Distinct Items
Bill     2
Bob      2
```

I remember using the array formula trick with `IF` to build an array based on a lookup value, but for the life of me I can't figure out how I then applied a distinct count to that subsequent array. It was something to do with `FREQUENCY`, but that only works with numbers and I haven't even been able to replicate that when I've tried just numbers. Here I've played around with both `SUM(1/COUNTIF(RANGE,RANGE))` and `SUMPRODUCT(1/COUNTIF(RANGE,RANGE))`.

Specifically, with Bill in `D2` and Bob in `D3` I've arrived at this array formula (placed in `E2` and `E3`):

`{=SUM(IF($A$2:$A8=D2,1/COUNTIF($B$2:$B8,$B$2:$B8)))}`

(D3 is obviously substituted for D2 in cell `E3`.)

It's still way off, though. I'm using Evaluate Formula to trace it and I can see that the `COUNTIF` counts all the occurrences of each item, not just the ones belonging to the lookup.

Any pointers back in the right direction? It's really frustrating given that I cracked it once in the past.

*(I realise with  Excel 2013 I can do it with `Distinct Count` in a PivotTable, but I'm needing to do it outside of one here for a couple of reasons.)*

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT - FOUND IT - SEE ANSWER BELOW**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering my own question so that it will show up as having been resolved.

I went searching and came across this:

http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/706444-function-formula-excel-count-unique-values-matching-criteria.html

Here is the formula:

`=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF($A$2:$A$8=D2,MATCH($B$2:$B$8,$B$2:$B$8,0)),IF($A$2:$A$8=D2,MATCH($B$2:$B$8,$B$2:$B$8,0)))>0,1))`

I don't know how I did it before, but I'll take whatever I can get after facepalming all day on this.

Comment: @pnuts Duly noted - and done. Thanks for the prompt. (this was in response to a useful suggestion to move the answer from the OP into the body of the answer post, something I hadn't done at first.)

Comment: Thanks, I won't forget - it says I can do it after 2 days.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this array formula:

```
=SUM(IF(ROW($C$2:$C$6)-ROW($C$2)+1=IFERROR(MATCH($C$2:$C$6;IF($B$2:$B$6=A2;$C$2:$C$6);0);0);1;0))
```

Names in B2:B6, products in C2:C6 and name to look for in A2

Depending on your regional settings you may need to change field separator ";" by ","

Comment: Tried it out -- am getting #VALUE! error with this part of the formula: `MATCH($C$2:$C$6:IF($B$2:$B$6=A2,$A$2,$A$2),0)`.

Comment: I tried again, works 100%, the error #value appears if you dont Ctrl Shift Enter in the end (it is an array formula)

Comment: **apologies: you're right -- it DOES work**. I was doing CSE but I'd messed something up when I put it into my worksheet. Now can't decide what's best: your method or the one I found!